# How do I write a function that adds an element to a vector, allowing the element to be changed before insertion?

Tags: vector, rust

I'm trying to make a simple example involving a vector of structs to learn Rust. All examples of vectors in the Rust literature I've found only use vectors of integers.

I want to write a function aimed at filling a vector, allowing the possibility of the element to be inserted to be changed, I can't figure out what to do. I always got a compiler `error[E0308]: mismatched types` on 
the `push` method, because `elem` is a reference to a `Point`. So

- `push()` needs a `Point` structure because `v` is a vector of `Point`
- but if I want to modify `elem`, I need to pass a (mutable?) reference

What is the right thing to do?

```
// structure used everywhere in Rust examples
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i16,
    y: i16
}

fn add_element(v: &mut Vec<Point>, elem: &Point) {
    // modify element
    elem.x = 0;

    // add element
    v.push(elem);
}

// this example is meant to study a vector of structs
fn main() {
    // declare 2 points. By default, live on the stack
    let origin = Point {x:0, y:0};
    println!("origin address\t: {:p}", &origin);
    let mut p1 = Point {x:1, y:1};
    println!("p1 address\t: {:p}", &p1);    

    // declare a new vector of structs. Allocation is made in the heap
    // declare mutable because we'll add elements to vector
    let mut v: Vec<Point> = Vec::new();

    // add points
    add_element(&mut v, &origin);
    add_element(&mut v, &p1);    

    // change p1
    p1.x = 2;
    p1.y = 2;
}
```

Comment: Do know that you can declare a moved function argument as `mut`?

Comment: @FrancisGagné struct field re-initialization after drop / move is strange in general. See [this recent question and the linked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42566669/155423)

Answer (score 2):

Let's read the error messages together:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:12
   |
10 |     v.push(elem);
   |            ^^^^ expected struct `Point`, found &Point
   |
   = note: expected type `Point`
   = note:    found type `&Point`
```

The code is attempting to store a reference to a `Point` in a `Vec` that is declared to hold entire `Point`s. Since Rust is a statically- and strongly- typed language, the compiler tells you that you cannot do that. The fix is to accept a `Point` by value:

```
fn add_element(v: &mut Vec<Point>, elem: Point)
```

This leads to the next error:

```
error: cannot assign to immutable field `elem.x`
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     elem.x = 0;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You cannot change members of `elem` because it is not marked as mutable. Mutability of a value is a property of the binding, so let's do that:

```
fn add_element(v: &mut Vec<Point>, mut elem: Point)
```

Then change the calling of that function to adapt:

```
fn main() {
    let origin = Point { x: 0, y: 0 };
    let p1 = Point { x: 1, y: 1 };

    let mut v = Vec::new();

    add_element(&mut v, origin);
    add_element(&mut v, p1);
}
```

Note that neither `origin` nor `p1` need to be mutable because this function doesn't modify either while it owns it. It *transfers ownership* to `add_element`, which chooses to make it mutable.

> but if I want to modify `elem`, I need to pass a (mutable?) reference

As you can see, you can simply make the `elem` parameter mutable when transferring the entire value to the function. Since the function owns that value, it has full control over it, including choosing to make it mutable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was not (still) aware of the **mut** keyword in the fn argument. I wanted to make **origin** & **p1** mutable in order to play with them afterwards.

Comment: @Coeurdanis There is no afterwards; once they've been moved, they are gone from the caller.

Comment: Yep, Rust is a mindset shift: when using bindings and not refs, I have to keep in mind that once a fn grabs a value, it's gone for the caller. It a definitive move.