# Why is this field mutation allowed after drop?

Tags: rust

Why does the Rust compiler allow the field `A.b` to be mutated after the the value `a` has been moved into `drop`?

```
struct A {
    b: usize
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A { b: 0 };

    drop(a);

    a.b = 1; // <---- Why is this allowed?
}
```

Shouldn't the compiler give an error on that line?

(The compiler does give an error if you attempt to use the value after calling `drop()`)

**Further Investigation:**
I thought perhaps this was just because the compiler knew that the write was "dead" but it seems to be generating code to actually perform the write. The `MIR` for `main()` contains this:

```
bb0: {
    StorageLive(_1);                 // scope 0 at <anon>:6:9: 6:14
    _1 = A { b: const 0usize };      // scope 0 at <anon>:6:17: 6:27
    StorageLive(_3);                 // scope 1 at <anon>:8:10: 8:11
    _3 = _1;                         // scope 1 at <anon>:8:10: 8:11
    _2 = std::mem::drop::<A>(_3) -> bb1; // scope 1 at <anon>:8:5: 8:12
}

bb1: {
    StorageDead(_3);                 // scope 1 at <anon>:8:13: 8:13
    (_1.0: usize) = const 1usize;    // scope 1 at <anon>:10:5: 10:12
    _0 = ();                         // scope 1 at <anon>:5:11: 11:2
    StorageDead(_1);                 // scope 0 at <anon>:11:2: 11:2
    return;                          // scope 0 at <anon>:11:2: 11:2
}
```

(notice the `(_1.0: usize) = const 1usize;` line in `bb1`)

and a Debug build contains this assembly:

```
example::main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 16], 0
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 24], 0
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 32], 0
    mov     rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 32]
    call    core::mem::drop
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 16], 1 # <-- Notice this write
    add     rsp, 32
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Comment: [It is a known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21232) that doesn't seem to have a conclusion as of yet.

Comment: Ah, this is a duplicate. I tried searching before posting but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Ah, very nice. I knew this was asked but couldn't find the duplicate either, so this will be a very nice signpost.